# I don’t know what LEGO piece this is with a large hole going through its center

Tags: part-identification

[image: unknown piece]

Can anyone tell me what LEGO piece this is?

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.StackExchange. Please edit your question title to be more descriptive regarding the piece in question. As currently written, it has zero search value for future readers.

Answer (score 29):

Technic, Engine Cylinder with Side Slots

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2850

Answer (score 5):

This one is used to build engines, used in V or I engines like this: [link](https://www.lego.com/en-my/kids/videos/technic/lltechnicvideoquickbuildvengineglobalaug18-72a8b84a0c864c79a040a2645755444a)

Comment: There's a flat configuration too. Look at the engine of this one: https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/porsche-911-rsr-42096